# Запрос ко многим базам SQLite

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Имеются базы данных в формате SQLite, в них таблицы. Всё это представлено в виде множества файлов на диске с расширением SQLite. Во все базы нужно внести однотипные изменения. Написал запрос, открываю каждую DB Browser Sqlite и запускаю запрос. Хочу как-то автоматизировать процесс, есть ли такой инструмент, чтобы отправить однотипный запрос ко всем базам. В какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: Смотреть в сторону любого скриптового языка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге я использовал .sh скрипты в Debian, чтобы автоматически вносить однотипные изменения в БД.